# How to add static c-library (libsrtp) to Android-Project using NDK

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

so I'm relatively new to Android-NDK and trying to add an uncompiled c-library to android. 
I've downloaded the library's source from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/srtp) and followed [these](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/6tt6SHxAU3E/G6hv16KnkecJ) instructions to create a static library (.a-File) from the downloaded files using ndk-build. 
So now I have a folder-structure that looks like this: 
 
-srtp 
--include (srtp.h, crypto.h)
--srtp (srtp.c...)
--obj
---local
----armeabi
-----**libsrtp_static.a**

In my Android-project I want to include srtp.h in a c-file inside my /jni/ folder. I've tried to just add the .a-file to the /jni folder but than it says "srtp.h no such file or direcotry". If I add the entire srtp-folder to the project and include the header with "srtp/include/srtp.h" it compiles but fails to link the source as I get the error "Undefined reference to *srtp-function-call*"

Here's my Android.mk (parts of it copied from Android.mk within the downloaded source):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE    := ndk1 #name of my project
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c #name of the c-source file

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)


LOCAL_PATH:= /home/dev/programing/srtp
common_SRC_FILES := \
    srtp/srtp.c \
    srtp/ekt.c \
    crypto/cipher/cipher.c \
    #...more files like that
common_CFLAGS := \
    -DPOSIX -iquote$(LOCAL_PATH)/crypto/include \
    -Werror \
    -Wno-ignored-qualifiers \
    -Wno-sign-compare \
    -Wno-missing-field-initializers
common_C_INCLUDES = $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
# For the device
# =====================================================
# Device static library
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
ifneq ($(TARGET_ARCH),x86)
    LOCAL_NDK_VERSION := 5
    LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := 9
endif
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libsrtp_static.a
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += $(common_CFLAGS)
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /home/dev/programing/srtp/include
    LOCAL_MODULE:= libsrtp_static
    LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the reference to libsrtp_static from your lib (ndk1) declaration :

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libsrtp_static
```

Also, you don't need to copy all the strp sources to your project, only add this to your static prebuilt library definition

```
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += /home/dev/programing/srtp/include
```

This path will then be automatically added to the `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` of your library that is using the library.

Are you building libsrtp or just using a prebuilt static library ? If you're using a prebuilt (lib*.a), replace `BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY` with `PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY` and set only the .a as SRC_FILE:

In summary, once **libstrp_static.a** is built, this should work:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE    := ndk1 #name of my project
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c #name of the c-source file
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libsrtp_static
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := /home/dev/programing/srtp/libsrtp_static.a #check path to libsrtp_static.a 
    LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += /home/dev/programing/srtp/include
    LOCAL_MODULE:= libsrtp_static
    LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```